# FluentBit: Where does field in logs for pod come from?

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit, graylog

I have k8s cluster with сonfigured **fluent-bit** logger. Configuration of fluent-bit:

```
custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name docker_no_time
        Format json
        Time_Keep Off
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level info
        Parsers_File parsers.conf
        Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On

    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        Tag kube.*
        DB /var/log/fluent-bit-kube.sqlite
        Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines On

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On

    [FILTER]
        Name modify
        Match kube.*
        Add kube_cluster_name dev-k8s

    [OUTPUT]
        Name gelf
        Match kube.*
        Host log.my-graylog.ru
        Port 12201
        Mode udp
        Gelf_Short_Message_Key log
        Gelf_Host_Key dev.k8s
        Compress false
```

But! Single pod(container) has additional field: **MachineName** . All messages for this pod is correct, correct multiline. Other pods doesn't contains this field. In **.log* files inside `/var/log/containers/` this field is absent for all containers, including that special pod (with `MachineName`).

If look at all the logs from cluster in graylog can be seen field **kubernetes_container_name**.
But messages incorrect, breaked multiline.

What other settings can modify log messages ? What else can I check to find the answer?

My goal is to add **MachineName** field for all pods in cluster